# Create a PKCS7 from hash

Tags: cryptography, sign, pkcs#7

I have doubts in a task I have to do. Is there a way to sign data remotely?; what I mean by this is can I create a pcks#7 remotely. Now the pfx would only be in the clients machine. I want to avoid retreiving from a remote server all the data that must be digitally signed and send it to the clients. Or is it valid to get a hash from the remote data and sign that hash with the clients pfx?

Any pointers, I'll appreciated...

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Who are you proposing to do the signing, the client or the server? Where is the data to be signed, on the client or the server? Why is the data being signed and where and who will verify the signature?

Comment: Eh, yes, a CMS signature is generally performed over a structure contains a hash over the signed data. Even if it wasn't, the signature itself is also calculated using a hash value. So it's possible, but you 1) must make sure you know what you are signing and 2) you need a detached signature with some kind of identification of the data.

Comment: Well, my proposal is, unless there's another better way, to sign a data hash on the clients side. I want to avoid retrieving all data to be signed and send it to the client. The signature will be verified on the server side.

Comment: Theoretically you don't have an issue, so get to it.